# Check for an existence of a class from document selector

Tags: jquery

How to check for an existence of a class of the clicked element from  **document** selector

Eg:

```
$(document).on("click",function(){
  // function to check the element class on which It's clicked
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", function (e){
    console.log( e.target.className );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uQn8r/

---

If you want to check if the element that was clicked has a certain class, use this:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e){
    if ( $(e.target).hasClass('someClass') ) {
        // run some code...
    }
});
```

---

If you only want to run the function if the target element has a specific class, use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function (e){
    // run some code...
});
```

Comment: may be `$(e.target).hasClass('xyz')`

Comment: Don't you need `null` after `"click"`?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour - You most definitely don't.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's "hasClass()" method: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

```
if($(e.target).hasClass("myClass")){
     // Do something
}
```